# Mac OS X Mavericks: How do I remove the quarantine flag from my Sparsebundle mount?

Tags: macos, operating-system, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded to Mac OS X Mavericks. I have a sparsebundle image which is mounted with the "quarantine" attribute, which prevents me from running any shell scripts on the volume. Here is what I get when I run "mount" in terminal:

`/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/Source (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners, quarantine, mounted by crith)`

I've tried running the following command on the sparsebundle image:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Source.sparsebundle`

But, the volume is still mounting with the "quarantine" flag set! Any advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the token inside the sparsebundle is what causes the image to be mounted with the quarantine flag. To fix, run this:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Source.sparsebundle/token`